# Copy Vector in a Vector in Java

Tags: java, collections

I'd like to copy a vector to another. The problem is that if I change the vector `v1`, the second vector `v2` is changing too.  My goal is to keep the copy intact even if I change the source vector.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;

public class CopyElementsOfVectorToVectorExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create first Vector object
    Vector v1 = new Vector();

    //Add elements to Vector
    v1.add("1");
    v1.add("2");
    v1.add("3");

    //create another Vector object
    Vector v2 = new Vector(v1.size());  

    v2.setSize(v1.size());
    Collections.copy(v2,v1);


    System.out.println("After copy, Second Vector Contains : " + v2);  
  }}
```

How can I keep the second copy intact?

Comment: How does your code-snippet illustrate the problem?!

Comment: This question needs a little more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the problem is if I change the vector v1, the second v2 is changing too ...My goal is to keep the copy intact even if I change the source vector`

This is because `Collections.copy(v2,v1)` make a ***sallow copy*** not **deep copy**.

Make **deep copy** of your `Vector`.

Apologize for previous answer.

**Edit:**

I am assuming that your `vector` is containing objects of type `Serializable`. With this approach you can get a deep copy of your collection.

```
static public Object deepCopy(Object oldObj) throws Exception {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // A
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos); // B
        // serialize and pass the object
        oos.writeObject(oldObj); // C
        oos.flush(); // D
        ByteArrayInputStream bin = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                bos.toByteArray()); // E
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(bin); // F
        // return the new object
        return ois.readObject(); // G
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in ObjectCloner = " + e);
        throw (e);
    } finally {
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: ...right. For *Strings* however, this makes little sense, since you can't change them anyway.

Comment: You can use your class rather than String.Updated the answer.

Comment: i have used your code , but when i modify the source , the copie is modified also !

Comment: This is *not* a deep copy, it’s a *shallow copy*, and it’s the same as just using the `Vector` copy constructor.

Comment: That's not a deep copy. It does nothing more than `new Vector(originalVector)`.

Comment: i understand that there is no solution in my case ?

Comment: @user1514847: There would be a solution if you had an identifiable problem. The code you posted doesn't have the problem you describe. Post code that reproduces the problem you have, and we'll find a solution.

Comment: @user1514847 No, there is a solution. You haven’t shown us the problem. The code you posted works, and nobody here understands what you want. By the way, this is quite frustrating.

Comment: //My object in the vector are

public class A {
public  int x;
 public A(int y)
 {this.x=y;}
 public void set(int y)
 {x=y;}

}

Comment: import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Vector;
 
public class CopyElementsOfVectorToVectorExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     
  
    Vector v1 = new Vector <A> ();
    A a=new A(2);
    v1.add(a);
    Vector v2 = new Vector <A> (v1.size());  
    v2.setSize(v1.size());
    Collections.copy(v2,v1);
    System.out.println("Before copy, Second Vector Contains : " + ((A) v2.get(0)).x); 
    ((A) v1.get(0)).set(5);
    System.out.println("Original vector : " + ((A) v1.get(0)).x); 
    System.out.println("After copy, Second Vector Contains : " + ((A) v2.get(0)).x); }}

Comment: @amicngh: i try with your code :public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
 Vector v1 = new Vector <A> (); 
 A a=new A(2);
 v1.add(a); 
 Vector v2 = new Vector <A> (v1.size());
 v2.setSize(v1.size()); 
  for(int i=0;i<v1.size();i++){
  v2.addElement(deepCopy(v1.get(i)));
  }
 
 System.out.println("Before MAJ, Second Vector Contains : " + ((A) v2.get(0)).x); 
 ((A) v1.get(0)).set(5); System.out.println("Original vector : " + ((A) v1.get(0)).x);
 System.out.println("After MAJ, Second Vector Contains : " + ((A) v2.get(0)).x);}}

Comment: but i have this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at mypackage.CopyElementsOfVectorToVectorExample.main

Comment: i have resolved the problem, i have delete this instruction v2.setSize(v1.size());

Comment: in my code i have assumed that vector containing serializabe objects.

Answer (score 14):

Your code above is fine, although too complex. It could be reduced to

```
Vector copy = new Vector(original);
```

Also, you should avoid Vector, and use ArrayList instead.

Comment: @user1514847 Seriously? Why? They are deprecated for non-cross-thread usage, and even there you have better data structures.

Comment: @user1514847: there is no way your above code exhibits the behavior you're describing. Edit your question, and paste code that reproduces the problem that you're seeing. I have the feeling that you're not storing Strings in your vector, and that you're not modifying the vector, but the objects it contains. String being immutable, what I describe is impossible with Strings.

Comment: no it's not a string, i have used an objects that i create it

Comment: @KonradRudolph hes probably using J2ME or Blackberry which do not support ArrayList

Answer (score 7):

> [...] ***I change the vector v1, the second v2 is changing too ...My goal is to keep the copy intact even if I change the source vector ..***

The vector contains *references* to objects. If you change the objects, then the change will be visible from both vectors.

I believe what you're after is a [*deep copy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy).

Comment: No, that’s not what the OP wants. he probably wants a shallow copy (his objects are immutable anyway). OP is probably a bit confused, since his code already does what he wants (but see JB’s answer).

Comment: If the OP is experiencing that a change in vector 1 affects vector 2, I doubt that he's using strings in his "real" code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Below code to clone a vector.

```
Vector v1 = new Vector();

//Add elements to Vector
v1.add("1");
v1.add("2");
v1.add("3");

//create another Vector object
Vector v2 = (Vector)v1.clone();
```